# What happens if we make an allocated pointer to an object as nil?

Tags: objective-c

I have seen this code in a couple of places.

```
XYZ *xyz = [[XYZ alloc] init];
```

but in dealloc instead of `[xyz release]`;

people have used `self.xyz =  nil`;

Won't this cause a memory leak?

EDIT : It was not `xyz =  nil` as I wrote initially, it was `self.xyz = nil`,
It was a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, that is a memory leak, however if XYZ is declared as property eg

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) XYZ* xyz;

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.xyz = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

this is not a memory leak, maybe the ones you saw were actually this?

Edit:
then it is not a memory leak, the reason being, setter is created by property, it'll be something similar to the one below

```
- (void)setXYZ:(XYZ *)newXyz
{
    [xyz release];
    xyz = [newXyz retain];
}
```

because newXyz is nil, sending retain to nil does nothing, while the old xyz is being released by the setter. Memory is managed properly in this case

Comment: Even if it was a property, it still would be leaking, the original alloc wouldn't be freed.

Comment: xyz = [[XYZ alloc] init]; so the pointer to the new allocated object is stored in our "xyz" iVar, then when we set it to nil using self.xyz = nil, the setter will be called, [xyz release]; is part of the setter, so the original alloc does get freed.

Comment: well as long you don't allocate object using self.xyz = [[XYZ alloc] init];

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the project settings. If ARC is enabled, then, no, there should be no problems. However, if the project does not have ARC enabled, then there could be some problems with memory leaking.

Comment: Thanks. I came to know about ARC becoz of your answer but my answer was actually wrt to properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only for retained properties and using setter ( `self.propertyToBeReleased=nil` or `[self setProPropertyToBeReleased:nil` )
So if you assign a property nil, the old one is released, and the pointer is pointing to nil.

You shouldn't do it with iVars. Because the data is just leaking(data is not released, but there is no pointer to it->cannot be released anymore).

Comment: `xyz = nil;` will still cause a leak even if `xyz` is a property unless preceeded by `self.` because the setter is never called (and the setter is in charge of releasing).